# What is the best way in PHP to reduce an array by an array of known keys?

Tags: php

I am browsing the [array functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) in PHP, trying to find the magical wand(s) to do this.

Here is what I have.

```
$images = array(...);

$randomImages = array_rand($images, 3);

// Now I want to reduce $images by the keys in $randomImages
```

What PHP array functions can I leverage for this?

#### Update

I ended up answering my own question after digging for a while, but I'm still open to alternate solutions :)

Comment: Dont know, if its me, but I dont understand ... You have an array of images, but what is, what you want to get?

Comment: @KingCrunch I want it reduced by the keys returned by `array_rand()`, i.e. the subset of randomly chosen array members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came up with this, and it works well...

```
$images = array_intersect_key($images, array_flip($randomImages));
```

I can also do it using...

```
shuffle($images);
$images = array_slice($images, 0, 3);
```

(This uses [Andre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599874/what-is-the-best-way-in-php-to-reduce-an-array-by-an-array-of-known-keys/4599942#4599942) as a basis).

Comment: You compare the numeric keys of an array with images? :?

Comment: @KingCrunch Check out [`array_rand()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php), it may be of assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a different approach just because it fits in one line:

```
$images = array_intersect_key($images, array_slice(shuffle(array_keys($images)), 0, 3));
```

I like one-liners.

Comment: I forgot about `shuffle()` ! Thanks for your answer. +1

Comment: BTW, if I was to use `shuffle()`, couldn't I then remove all references to the keys (because they are not important here) ? Also, it seems `shuffle()` takes the array by reference.

Comment: Yes, with either string keys or numerical keys, this will work but remove them at the end to avoid two function calls when you only need one.

Comment: [See my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599874/what-is-the-best-way-in-php-to-reduce-an-array-by-an-array-of-known-keys/4599876#4599876) - it seems to work and is more terse.